# Cant get the view to show up on the TeamStudio Unplugged app

Tags: xpages, teamstudio-unplugged

I have tried putting the view into a custom control and then putting the custom control in the UnpMain.xsp, and I have tried putting it directly into the UnpMain.xsp, neither of these works. I can get other components to show, such as text fields, check-boxes, labels, and so on but for whatever reason the view will not show in my app, when I open the UnpMain.xsp within a browser it shows perfectly fine, so it is not an ACL issue.

Comment: Source code rulez. Post a simple sample of what you try to do as an update to your question

Comment: Can you open the view in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Stephan is right: source code would be useful, but I'll make an educated guess...)

I'm assuming you've added an `<xp:viewPanel>` to the XPage. That won't work, because Unplugged doesn't support that control. See also [this](http://docs.teamstudio.com/display/UNPDOC/XPages) page with all supported controls.

It does however support the `<xp:repeat>` control. That also the way in Unplugged to add a list (view) to a page. For example:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView
        var="view1"
        viewName="default">
    </xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <xp:repeat
            id="repeat1"
            rows="30"
            value="#{view1}"
            var="row">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xp:link text="#{row.name}"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"doc.xsp?documentId=" + row.getUniversalID() + "&action=editDocument"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:link>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xp:text
                        escape="true"
                        id="computedField2"
                        value="#{row.city}">
                    </xp:text>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xp:repeat>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

One more thing: I would recommend to download the latest version of the [XControls](http://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XControls) project. You can either start using that in your project or to take a look the source code.